# Laravel log external call

Tags: laravel, logging

I'm using a laravel plugin to make calls to an external API.

I have issues with the API so I'd like to log all the calls that happen to the API. I already log every incoming request with a middleware function. How can I log all calls from my server to the API?

Sidenote: The plugin uses guzzle and I know you can add logging there, but then I have to edit the plugin which is no good practice.

Comment: Since the logging seems to be required just for debugging purposes I don't think it is too bad of a practice to use guzzle to log it?

Comment: So you recommend to edit the vendor files from the plugin?

Comment: If you just want to check your api calls right now and revert the changes made after you solved your issue I don't think that is too big of a problem.

Comment: I was hoping for a better answer that didn't involve editing source code from the plugins.

Comment: I use to place my observers in `AppServiceProvider`